# Error in my thesis contact information -

Tags: publications

Having published my thesis on researchgate, I have noticed that the contact email in the text is incorrect. Some people have already downloaded it and may have even tried to contact me. My email in my Research gate profile is the right one, however, I would like to know how to fix this error. Should I delete and update the item on the Researchgate website? Does this affect the DOI or something like that?
Thank you all in advance.